# How to solve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/camel/impl/DefaultComponent?

Tags: apache-camel, osgi, apache-karaf, jbossfuse, apache-servicemix

I want to test a camel-component, written by a colleague and me. It runs on [Karaf](https://karaf.apache.org) and the following [camel](http://camel.apache.org) bundles are deployed:

```
80 │ Active  │  50 │ 2.17.1         │ camel-blueprint
81 │ Active  │  50 │ 2.17.1         │ camel-catalog
82 │ Active  │  50 │ 2.17.1         │ camel-core
```

The component and a blueprint that uses the component is deployed, too. I think that I missed to install a camel feature, which provides the class **DefaultComponent**, so I think it's not necessary to review the code.

I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/camel/impl/DefaultComponent
```

Comment: That class is from `camel-core` so it ought to be there. Maybe that error is caused by some other error which it hides somehow. Also check that the bundle you try to install have the right osgi imports etc. And also you need to tell more about what you do in that bundle that gets this error, maybe you dont have setup it correct for osgi etc.

Comment: I checked the existing [camel-components](https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/components) and noticed, that we forgot some osgi properties in mavens pom. So I set the properties **camel.osgi.export.pkg**, **camel.osgi.import.additional** and **camel.osgi.export.service** in the pom and now the ClassDef of DefaultComponent can be found. So you were right @ClausIbsen - we didn't set it up correctly for osgi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was that I did not set up the Maven project of the Camel component correctly. To avoid this you can start the development of a Camel component with an [archetype](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel.archetypes/camel-archetype-component).

So you could start like this:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.camel.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=camel-archetype-component -DarchetypeVersion=2.24.2
```